# Merge dataframes in rstudio by ID and YEAR

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge multiple data frames that have the same columns and individuals (ID's), the only difference is the year (one dataframe for each year), as shown in the images
[image][image]

I've already tried to use the function merge() but I'm unable to get any results. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a screenshot). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg